# android disable editText in a listview at particular position

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a listview in which I want to disable the `editText` at only first position. This is what I have done:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final PatientView patientView;

    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_add_session_view,null);
        patientView=new PatientView();
        patientView.edtSessionDescription= (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edtSessionDescription);
        patientView.edtSessionNumber= (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edtSessionNumber);
        patientView.txtSessionTime= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSessionTime);
        patientView.btnAdd= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        patientView.btnDelete= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        convertView.setTag(patientView);
    } else {
        patientView= (PatientView) convertView.getTag();
    }

    patientView.edtSessionNumber.setText(modelPatientArrayList.get(position).getSessionNumber());
    patientView.edtSessionNumber.setTag(position);
    patientView.edtSessionDescription.setText(modelPatientArrayList.get(position).getSessionDescription());
    patientView.txtSessionTime.setText(modelPatientArrayList.get(position).getTime());



    if(0==(Integer)patientView.edtSessionNumber.getTag()){
        patientView.edtSessionNumber.setEnabled(false);
    }

    patientView.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("tag position",(Integer) patientView.edtSessionNumber.getTag()+"");
            updateFirstSession(modelPatientArrayList.get(position), patientView.edtSessionDescription.getText().toString());

            modelPatientArrayList.clear();
            modelPatientArrayList.addAll(dbUtil.getPatientSession());
            patientView.btnAdd.setText("edit");
            patientView.btnAdd.setTag(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    patientView.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteFromDataBase(modelPatientArrayList.get(position));
            modelPatientArrayList.clear();
            modelPatientArrayList.addAll(dbUtil.getPatientSession());
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

But the problem is it is also disabling the edittext of other view after scrolling. Can anyone please tell what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ListView re-uses the views so you need to write code for both cases

```
patientView.edtSessionNumber.setEnabled( (position == 0) ? false : true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code , should solve your prolem.
if(position == 0)
patientView.edtSessionNumber.setEnabled(false);

Comment: i have tried but it also disables the 7 position edittext

Comment: Put patientView.edtSessionNumber.setTag(position); inside the initialization of convertView